# airflow DAG does not show previous attempt logs

Tags: airflow

I have few DAGs running the cluster, couple of DAGs succeeded after 4 attempts, but both of them not showing the previous attempts logs.

Failed to fetch log file from worker. 404 client Error: NOT FOUND for url:http://airflow-worker:8793/log/s3-copy/2022-04-16T11:30:00+00:00/1.log

Any ideas why Airflow UI is not displaying the logs? i also check the worker logs directory, it doesn't have the previous attempt logs.

Comment: HI what is your setup for logs ? Where does it reside ? S3, local disk. Please provide details so I can help.

Comment: The logs are stored on local disk, i can see the logs for only 1 attempt out of 4 attempts

Comment: By the way, airflow is running on EKS cluster with 5 airflow workers.

Comment: Do you know there’s more than one attempt actually happened?

Comment: Better approach is to store the logs in a permanent storage and use lifecycle to manage them

Comment: Also what is your local disk and what executor you are using

Comment: Yes, i can see 4 attempts and i see the log for 4th attempt. You mean permanent storage like S3? I am using KubernetesPod operator with Celery executor

Comment: Hi kumar. Everytime there is a retry your log file name should be 1.log,2.log etc. Is that happening ?

Comment: Yes, i could see the log files with attempt number, but in this case i only see 4.log. I don't see logs for previous attempts

Comment: @kumar Do you have any updates on this issue? I'm facing the same problem